# How to implement disaster recovery for AWS EKS across regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, amazon-eks, amazon-aurora, disaster-recovery

We need to implement DR as Active-Active across regions (Us-East-1 & Us-West-2). All our application are containerized and deployed in EKS.(There are few applications may deployed as EC2 or Lambda - event-driven).
Our high availability requirement is 99.999
Microservices are both stateless and stateful (Majority o microservices are stateless). We are using Amazon Aurora Database and multi-AZ is enabled. Primary DB in Us-East-1 & Secondary DB in Us-West-2.
Hence could you suggest the DR approach for our AWS-EKS as well as scenarios.

Comment: This is a multi-day consulting engagement and not a question for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

just two quick suggestions:

1. For Aurora DB, i assume you are using Aurora global db , that means the primary db writable with replica in the DR region. That means during disaster, the DR replica can be promoted. Aurora global db recently announced managed failover to further simplify your operation during failover: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/02/amazon-aurora-global-database-supports-managed-planned-failover/
2. For EKS cluster, understood you got both stateless and stateful workloads, if you already using GitOps tool like ArgoCD or FluxCD, they can easily deploy the workloads/configs to the DR cluster. For stateful workloads, you will need some kind of replication/backup/tactics. You may consider to use open source tool called Velero: https://velero.io/ for that.

Between AWS got a nice post on operating mult region EKS cluster: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/operating-a-multi-regional-stateless-application-using-amazon-eks/